# Http request in sencha touch 2

Tags: http, rest, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am very new to sencha touch 2.
I want to make a http request. basically I want to connect to google (http://www.google.com) and then check the http response if it's ok or not.

I have checked this code but I always get failure...

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'http://www.google.com',
        success : function(response, options) {
            Ext.Msg.alert("Success");
        },
        failure : function(response, options) {
            Ext.Msg.alert("Failure" + response.responseText + " "
                    + options.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Later on, I want to use this functionality to implement log-in for the application.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch on Chrome with params --disable-web-security. Next you have to possibility to make Ajax request ( without cross domain policy). On device you use web container not the browser to make a request.

Answer (score 0):

whene I try your code it's give me success alert.
but in console I get this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/?_dc=1330926850434. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

This error is because of that google sever not allowed ajax request from domin localhost.
If  you want to send requset on this url you have to use Jsonp .

Answer (score 0):

There is a Cross Domain policy which restricts user to fetch data by AJAX requests directly. So, from javascript if you want to do that, you have to use a [ScriptTagProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP) here.

If you are going to make a login mechanism and the data resides in same server (localhost for your case), you will not get any issue because you will be making the AJAX request from "localhost" to "localhost" ie, to same domain and then there will be no issue like this.

Otherwise, if you really want it to be cross domain, you can just write a server side code (I am showing in php - you should use cURL) to connect and get data - which doesn't require JSONP.

**Filename: action.php**

```
<?php
    print file_get_contents(http://www.google.com);
?>
```

**File name: Your js file**

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'action.php',
    success : function(response, options) {
        console.log(response);
        Ext.Msg.alert("Success");
    },
    failure : function(response, options) {
        Ext.Msg.alert("Failure" + response.responseText + " "
                + options.responseText);
    }
});
```